Understanding spaces of negative regularity
Let $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n$) be the space of functions with $k$ continuous derivatives, and $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Sobolev space $W^{2,s}$. Their dual spaces are commonly denoted as $C^{-k}$ or $H^{-s}$. Similar notations exist for duals to Holder spaces, Besov spaces...etc.
I had always thought the negative index was only notational, but it seems it has a genuine interpretation as "lacking regularity". For example, the space $C^{-k}$ can be seen as "lacking $k$ derivatives".
What justifies that the interpretation that a space with index $-k$ "lacks $k$ derivatives"? Why are distributions/dual spaces the right setting for functions that lack some degree of differential regularity?
